# Dynamic WTF Forms based on a config File

Tags: flask, flask-wtforms

I'm trying to generate a form definition based on a config file. The code is just for testing purposes:

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired
class B2BForm(FlaskForm):
  products = list()
  for i in range(0,4):
      products.append(StringField('Name asd '+str(i), validators=[DataRequired()]))
```

I then render my form:

```
{% for p in form.products %}
  <div class="form-group">
      <label for="password">Label: {{p.label}}</label>
      {% for error in p.errors %}
          <div style="color: red;">[{{ error }}]</div>
      {% endfor %}
    </div>
 {% endfor %}
```

which unfortunately does not work :( The loop works, but it can't render the itemsl. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think its your class construction. I believe wtf forms require a strict format; class attribute is a wtf_Field NOT a list of fields. Try instead

```
def index():
    def B2BForm():
        class _B2BForm(FlaskForm):
            prod_list = list()
            pass
        for i in range(4):
            setattr(_B2BForm, 'product_' + str(i), StringField('Name asd ' + str(i), validators=[DataRequired()]))
            _B2BForm.prod_list.append(str(i))
        return _B2BForm()
    return render_template('index.html', form=B2BForm())
```

[Note you can also do this type of construction with metaclasses and `__metaclass__`, and possibly within the def `__init__(self)`, but I haven't tried these and prefer the above construction form]

You then need to change your jinja2 to loop over your attributes 'product_0', 'product_1' etc, like this:

```
{% for p_int in form.prod_list %}
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password">Label: {{ form['product_'+p_int].label }}</label>
            {% for error in form['product_'+p_int].errors %}
                <div style="color: red;">[{{ error }}]</div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
{% endfor %}
```

You can also use this as a dynamic constructor so if your number of products change substitute 4 for N, and place N as an argument to the function. FlaskForms don't allow dynamic construction explicitly.

Comment: Yes, well the class definition was fine in my example. What solved it was the setattr function, though I have to do it outside of the class.
What I still not get is the loop part. I have only found hacks with exec that would allow to loop over variables. Any clues on that one?

Comment: @rapsli I have amended the answer and tested it works. Please accept the answer if you agree. Cheers

Comment: Works now! Though in your template code you are missing to actually print out the field: {{ form['product_'+p_int](size=32) }}. You are just outputting the label and the error.